# Ubuntu 22.04 - USB-C converter pluggin = no sound

Tags: 22.04, usb-c

I have a Dell XPS that comes with only USB-C ports. So I need a USB-C converter to USB and HDMI. When plugged in and with a monitor with HDMI input connected to it, everything works but the sound is gone. If I unplug the converter, or the HDMI cable, the sound is back.

Has anybody come across this problem?

Thanks